# Vue storybook example using v-model and template?

Tags: vue.js, storybook

How do i use `v-model` in `vue storybook`? In my case, it's just a custom component that a end user can use with `v-model`. I have the following example:

```
const dateRange = [
  new Date('2014/5/14').toISOString(),
  new Date('2015/2/2').toISOString(),
]

const Template = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
  components: { DateRangePicker },
  data: () => ({ dateRange }),
  props: Object.keys(argTypes),
  template:
    '<DateRangePicker v-bind="$props" v-model="dateRange" @input="onInput" />',
})

export const Default = Template.bind({})

Default.args = {
  dateRange: [], // if i remove this line, error is gone but i can't use a different default value for v-model via the template and all stories use the same value for `dateRange`.
}
```

If i do the above, then i end up with the following error: `The data property "dateRange" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead.`. I'm trying to write story cases with different examples of values passed in as `v-model`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are defining two instances of the same variable `dateRange`, one as a data with `data: () => ({ dateRange }),` and one as a prop with `v-bind="$props"`.

To fix this you'll need to remove the data or the prop.

If you remove the data, you'll have a different problem, and that will be that you're trying to modify the parent prop with a v-model. `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "dateRange"`

If you remove the prop, you can't modify it with the value of the control or exporting different cases.

**Solution**

1. Keep your prop dateRange for simplicity of creating different cases
2. rename the v-model, watch the dateRage prop of any changes and update the v-model.
3. You can decide to keep the bind with the dateRange or without it. *

```
const range = [
  new Date('2014/5/14').toISOString(),
  new Date('2015/2/2').toISOString(),
]

const Template = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
  components: { DateRangePicker },
  data: () => ({ range }),
  props: Object.keys(argTypes),
  template: '<DateRangePicker v-bind="propsWithoutRange" v-model="range" @input="onInput" />',
  watch: {
      dateRange(value) {
          if (value.length === 2) {
              this.range = value;
          }
      }
  },
  computed: {
      // *Optional
      propsWithoutRange() {
          const { dateRange, ...all } = this.$props;
          return all;
      }
  }
})

export const Default = Template.bind({})
Default.args = {
  dateRange: []
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `$` in the `v-bind` instruction, it's `propsWithoutRange`